# Реально ли ускорить данный генератор?

Tags: python, python-2.x, случайные-числа

Реально ли ускорить данный генератор?

```
import random
for x in xrange(1000000000) :
   with open('corpus.txt') as file:
       lines = random.sample(list(file), 3)
   print (" ".join(map(str.strip, lines)))
```

Comment: Один раз загрузите строки в список, а потом уже делайте `random.sample` из него, а не читайте каждый раз с диска.

Comment: @insolor Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем чтение строк из файла в список один раз (заодно сразу очищаем строки). А дальше уже делаем `random.sample` из готового списка.

```
import random

with open('corpus.txt') as file:
    lines = map(str.strip, file)  # list(map(str.strip, file)) для python3

for x in xrange(100):
    print (" ".join(random.sample(lines, 3)))
```

Выводить на экран сразу 1000000000 строк не стоит, тут скорость будет ограничена скоростью вывода на консоль. Тем более, что вы эти строки скорее всего все не сможете прочитать, т.к. например высота буфера консоли под Windows ограничена 300 строками (по-умолчанию). Лучше выводить в файл (или перенаправлять вывод в файл при запуске скрипта).

Comment: Хотя я тоже люблю мэпы...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, 1 - найдите место в pep8, где про это говорится (я только что смотрел, не нашел). 2 - это тот момент, в котором я не согласен с "общепринятым" мнением - map читается ясно и понятно: "применить функцию к каждому элементу последовательности", а list comprehension читается примерно как "применить применить функцию к i, где i - каждый элемент из последовательности file". В обоих случаях (и с map и с comprehension) можно накрутить так, что будет совершенно нечитаемо. В простом случае, как в данном ответе, ИМХО map более читаем.

Comment: Я тоже не нашел это место. Я это слышал от кого-то из участников тут. А мэп тут действительно хорошо читается. Хотя мой вариант ни чуть не хуже.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonicam это stackoverflow на русском, Поэтому комментарии нужно оставлять на русском языке